# Why are media queries impacting element positioning?

Tags: css

If I use a media query to control CSS for a single max screen width I can control the position of elements displayed at that screen width as you would expect (e.g. using 'top', 'left', etc.).

But if I add breakpoints, then I can no longer control the position of elements in this way. Why?

For example, here in the CSS I have a media query for '1ST WIDTH' which leads to content rendering as you would expect. But, if you uncomment the media query for '2ND WIDTH', these new position values are used by the browser even at the 1st width. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="text-one">
            Some text
        </div>
        <div class="text-two">
            A bit more text
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
  *{
    margin: 0;
  }
:root {
    font-size: 50px;
}
/* 1ST WIDTH */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .main-container {
        background-color: rgb(239, 237, 244);
        /* position: relative; */

    }
    .text-one {
        text-align: left;
        top: 35%;
        left: 5%;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 1rem;
        border: 3px solid red;
    }
    .text-two {
        text-align: left;
        top: 70%;
        left: 5%;
        position:absolute;
        font-size: 0.5rem;
        border: 3px solid purple;
    }
}

/* 2ND WIDTH */
/* @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .main-container {
        background-color: rgb(239, 237, 244);

    }
    .text-one {
        text-align: left;
        top: 5%;
        left: 5%;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 1rem;
        border: 3px solid red;
    }
    .text-two {
        text-align: left;
        top: 70%;
        left: 5%;
        position:absolute;
        font-size: 0.5rem;
        border: 3px solid purple;
    }
} */
```

Comment: because `max-width: 600px` applies to 480 as well. use `@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 600px)`

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If the width of the browser is `480px` or less then it is:

- Less then that max-width of 480px so the first media query applies
- Less then that max-width of 600px so the second media query applies

Then the rules of [the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) determine how rulesets which match the same element override each other.

Given you use the same selectors in each media query, step 4 —  if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins — applies.

Every rule in the second media query overrides the matching one in the first media query.

When designing your media queries:

1. Pick your base style (generally "mobile (or smallest) first" is recommended)
2. Put that one first
3. Design subsequent media queries to override the earlier ones

So if you want to go with mobile first

1. Put your mobile styles outside of any media query
2. Use `min-width` to selectively override them and **not** `max-width`.

If you want to go with desktop first, then **reverse the order** of your media queries (and, again, put the first (default) set of rulesets outside of any media query.